# Flutter generate list of widget in ternary operator prompt "Expected an Identifier"

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to generate a list of widget after a null check for my object, but I get an error of "Expected an Identifier". The below is my example code:

```
Column(
  children: [
    <condition>
    ? for (var A in <List of object>) <MyWidget>
    : const SizedBox(height: 20, width: 20)
  ],
),
```